# Why make User VO with Spring data mongo?

Tags: spring, mongodb, architecture, annotations, spring-data-mongodb

I am studying mongo db and Spring framework.
I believe one of strength of mongodb is expendable Structure, so user can easily add or remove member data.

However, I found many examples with User document(with `@Document`like [this](https://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/spring-data-mongodb-hello-world-example/)). If use VO like that user should compile java class whenever field adds or removes, right?

I think people using this way, since this kind of structure have a point. I want to know why. To me, it feels more suitable use `Map<String, Object>` to use.

Thanks for answering my fundamental question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the answer with the below points:

(1) By mapping a `Value Object` with `@Document`, you can represent a java object (in the heap) with a `document` inside a `MongoDB` `collection` (like `User`, `Product`, etc..) which is called **Object to Document Mapping (ODM) and you can use frameworks like Spring Data MongoDB, Hibernate OGM**, etc.. for this. The advantage is to store/retrieve documents by using the power of the ODM frameworks without reimplementing boilerplate code for accessing the database.

You can look at [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/) on this point on the features of Spring Data framework and it manages to store/retrieve the documents easily.

If you don't follow this, you will end up in reimplementing **boilerplate code** for the whole `Data Access Layer`.

(2) Also, using `Map<String, Object>` for each and every type of data is against to OOP, so you should represent the data with your business terms (like Product document, Department document, etc..).